# Was Christopher Columbus involved in the slave trade?

Tags: history, christopher-columbus

It seems to be common knowledge on the internet that Columbus was involved in the slave trade.

I just saw [this on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/thinkprogress/photos/a.201001406578004.58230.200137333331078/1375289495815850/?type=3) and thought I would try to find how true the quote is to what we know Columbus wrote.

[[image: columbus quote from facebook]

Comment: The [Columbus'es wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Columbus) has wealth of information with citations. tl;dr; Yes. He was a slaver and big tyrant.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics, Mark!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) The claim from Facebook already has a question about it, so I closed it as a duplicate. The question in the title isn't quite the same, but @Euphoric's comment probably covers that.